# Velocity word problem with circle.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Two kids starts to run from the same point and the same direction of circled running area with perimeter 400m. The velocity of each kid is constant. The first kid run each circle in 20 sec less than his friend. They met in the first time after 400 sec from the start. Q: Find their velocity.

I came with one equation:

400/v1 +20 = 400/v2

But what is the second equation? ("They met in the first time after 400 sec from the start.")

Comment: When they first met, after the start, the first child has run 400m more than the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second equation is 
$$(v_1-v_2)\times 400=400\ \ (\text{why?}).$$

Another form is
$$v_1\times 400-v_2\times 400=400.$$

Or the following form might be easier to understand :

$$v_1\times 400=v_2\times 400+400.$$

Comment: I am a little confused. Can we surely say the right hand side is $400$ and not $800$ or $1200$.In that case any multiple of $400$?

Comment: How about the second equation I wrote? It represents 'the difference'.

Comment: I don't understand. :(

Comment: If they meet with each other for the first time, this means that the difference between the two is $400$. If $800$ as you say, this means the first kid meet the second kids for the second time. You can consider the difference between the two. not each kid.

Comment: Ok,I get it. FOR THE FIRST TIME ! Overlooked that one.

Comment: @user119820 Suppose A and B have started from point P on a circle. A is slower and B is faster. Then B must have completed one complete round before meeting A for the first time right ? That is what he meant with that equation.

Comment: @user119820: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

first equation:

400/v1-400/v2=20    (we are assuming v2 is fast)

second equation: they meet first time after 400 sec:

400v2-400v1=400   ( because to meet first v1 again v2 cover 400 meter more)

So Ans will be v2= 5 M per sec
v1= 4 M per sec

Hope this will help you